# How can I remove a function and all object/handlers in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this:

```
var InitScrollbar = function () {
... variables, object, handlers, ecc
}
```

and on resize I'd like to destroy it and all variables/handlers/objects inside it. Tried with:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    InitScrollbar = null;
    //InitScrollbar();
});
```

but the handler inside it, after a resize, works again.
How can I destroy all?

Comment: You need to manually remove or disable the handlers.

Comment: I agree with SLaks - you are probably hooking it up to an event somewhere and that isn't getting removed just because you set a reference to null at once place.

Comment: ah, just read your question again. ignore my answer, gonna rewrite it in a sec

Comment: need to show more code to get answers with best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a sort of *dispose* method to invoke, eg:

```
var InitScrollbar = function () {
   // variables, object, handlers, ecc
   this.Dispose = function(){
      //clear / detach all your handlers here
   }
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    InitScrollbar.Dispose();
    //InitScrollbar();
});
```

EDITED:
As you aren't instancing InitScrollbar, you should change approach, try this:

```
var InitScrollbar = function () {
   // variables, object, handlers, ecc   
}

var DisposeScrollbar = function(){
   //clear / detach all your handlers here
   //take care of correctly reference to InitScrollbar properties
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    DisposeScrollbar();
});
```

Comment: It says `InitScrollbar.Dispose is not a function`

Comment: Have you declared it as in my example? Does it get declared *before* it gets called by window.resize event?

Comment: @markzzz how do you call it? `new InitScrollbar`? Can you show how you use it?

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas you do not _need_ the `this`

Comment: @qwertynl for sure, it was a mistype by copy/paste. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You would have to **manually** remove all of the handlers.

---

What you *could* do is clone the elements without the handlers and replace the old elements with the new cloned ones, but I **would not** advise this method.